# Ef core 3.0 gives error when inserting record 'The property 'Id' on entity type 'ChannelTypeT' could not be found'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, ef-core-3.0

I have .net core 3.0 api with auto mapper.

I am getting one issue with my mapping. below I have listed my entities.

```
[Table(name: "ChannelType")]
public class ChannelType : FullAuditedEntity<string>
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(06)]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ChannelTypeT ChannelTypeT { get; set; }
}
```

And the ChannelTypeT  entity will be like this.

```
[Table(name: "ChannelTypeT")]
public class ChannelTypeT
{
    [StringLength(02)]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    #region Primary Key derived from Foreign key for Config tabels        
    [Required]
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey(name: "ChannelTypeId")]
    public string ChannelTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ChannelType ChannelType { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Now, simply this means when I insert one ChannelType, the code should insert a new record in ChannelTypeT too, with same Id as ChannelTypeId. here is snap of that.

[image]

Here are my **Dto classes.**

```
public class ChannelTypeDtoIncluding
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ChannelTypeTDto ChannelTypeT { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelTypeTDto
{
    public string ChannelTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My auto mapper mappings.

```
CreateMap<ChannelTypeT, ChannelTypeTDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ChannelType, ChannelTypeDtoIncluding>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ChannelTypeT.ChannelTypeId))
            .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ChannelTypeT.Id))
            .ReverseMap();
```

And finally here is my post method.

```
 [HttpPost("InsertIncluding")]
    public IActionResult PostIncluding([FromBody]ChannelTypeDtoIncluding model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Id))
            return new NotFoundResult();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        Response<ChannelType> itemToReturn = _service.Insert(_mapper.Map<ChannelTypeDtoIncluding, ChannelType>(source: model));
        if (itemToReturn.IsSuccess == true)
            return new OkObjectResult(_mapper.Map<ChannelType, ChannelTypeDtoIncluding>(source: itemToReturn.Data));
        else
            return new ObjectResult(itemToReturn.ErrorMessage) { StatusCode = 500 };
    }
```

But here in this method, when I tries to map my model, it gives me error. below is the error description.

> The property 'Id' on entity type 'ChannelTypeT' could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.

My mapper will update **ChannelType -> Id to ChannelTypeT -> ChannelTypeId**.
I think issue is at the mapper config, But not sure where I am doing mistake.

Any idea on this will be a great help.

Comment: Please add code where you map entities with automapper

Comment: well I have used Dto's too. so it will create more confusion to readers over here. so I choose not to add them.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what 2 entities you want to map where it's needed to map `ChannelType.Id` to `ChannelTypeT.ChannelTypeId`. Are you doing `mapper.Map<ChannelType, ChannelTypeT>()`?

Comment: yes. the result I will need is a map of `ChannelType.Id` to `ChannelTypeT.ChannelTypeId`. I am also doing a mapping for that as you noted.

Answer (score 2):

Create mapping for `ChannelType` to `ChannelTypeT` and specify required connection using `ForMember`

```
CreateMap<ChannelType, ChannelTypeT>()
    .ForMember(c => c.ChannelTypeId, m => m.MapFrom(ct => ct.Id));
```

Comment: I think I must need to add Dto to my question. althogh your answer seems correct but it is not working as expected.

Comment: can you quickly check this, I have updated my question again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo , you could refer to

1. For the ForeignKey `ChannelTypeId` in `ChannelTypeT` model , you should modify like below , refer to [ForeignKey Attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute)

   ```
   [Table(name: "ChannelTypeT")]
   public class ChannelTypeT
   {
       [StringLength(02)]
       public string Lang { get; set; }
       public string Text { get; set; }

       #region Primary Key derived from Foreign key for Config tabels        
       [Required]
       [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
       [ForeignKey(name: "ChannelType")]
       public string ChannelTypeId { get; set; }
       public virtual ChannelType ChannelType { get; set; }
       #endregion
   }
   ```
2. Mapping file

   ```
   public class MapperProfile: Profile
   {
      public MapperProfile()
     {
       CreateMap<ChannelTypeT, ChannelTypeTDto>().ReverseMap();
       CreateMap<ChannelType, ChannelTypeDtoIncluding>()
           .ForMember(d => d.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ChannelTypeT.Text))
           .ReverseMap();
     }
   }
   ```
3. Post method

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("/InsertIncluding")]
   public IActionResult PostIncluding([FromBody]ChannelTypeDtoIncluding model)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Id))
           return new NotFoundResult();

       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           return BadRequest(ModelState);

       ChannelType data = _mapper.Map<ChannelTypeDtoIncluding, ChannelType>(source: model);
       _context.ChannelType.Add(data);
       _context.SaveChanges();
       return new OkObjectResult(_mapper.Map<ChannelType, ChannelTypeDtoIncluding>(source: data));
   }
   ```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, my mapping started working fine. I am still gettting this error of Id. seems issue with .net core.

Comment: if I add one more property Id as primary key and fk ChannelTypeId  in ChannelTypeT, it works fine.but if tries to keep ChannelTypeId  as pk and fk, it's giving error.

Comment: What's your `_service.Insert()` and `FullAuditedEntity<string>` ?

Comment: `_service.Insert()` has code with repository pattern. nothing fancy over there. it's simple insertion as you did in the answer. `FullAuditedEntity` is base class with properties like create date, edited date, deletion flag etc. it also has primary key so when you pass `string`, data type of id will be a string.

Comment: Here is my [demo](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EVJlXY3-RVVDh514ZD7bKN0Bk58g6G50gr-iFB0SQKcF0g?e=4bJlNc) , you could check the difference . If you still have the issue ,could you share a complete demo that can reprocude the issue?